# How to make a form in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to try ionic/angular 2, and  I can't figure out how to create a form. How can I do this?

Comment: How on earth is this question off-topic?  stackoverflow seems determined to make itself unusable

Comment: The question is "How do I create a form in Ionic/ angular 2". That's a good question. The section requesting a tutorial could be ignored if it is so against the rules.

Answer (score 24):

To begin with, let's assume a simple case of creating a login form.

- form:

  - (input) username
  - (input) password
  - (button) login

Your .html file:

```
        <form [ngFormModel]="loginForm" (submit)="login($event)">
            <ion-input stacked-label>
                <ion-label>Username</ion-label>
                <input type="text" ngControl="username">
            </ion-input>

            <ion-input stacked-label>
                <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
                <input type="password" ngControl="password">
            </ion-input>

            <div padding>
                <button block type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

In your .js file:

```
import {FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';

export class LoginPage {

  constructor(form: FormBuilder) {
    // Create a new form group
    this.loginForm = form.group({ // name should match [ngFormModel] in your html
      username: ["", Validators.required], // Setting fields as required
      password: ["", Validators.required]
  }

  // This is called on form submit
  login(event) {
    console.log(this.loginForm.value) // {username: <usename>, password: <password> }
    event.preventDefault();
  }

}
```

[Reference](http://learnangular2.com/forms/)

Comment: I found that for some reason this solution doesn't work with the `<ion-input stacked-label>` elements. The label is invisible, the input has no border and the submit button does not become enabled when the user inputs values into the form. Without the elements, the solution works fine.

Comment: hey @PhilD. have you come any further on that problem? i am experiencing the same

Comment: @divramod I haven't tried getting it working with `<ion-input stacked-label>` since my comment. It worked without it and I don't know enough about 'stacked-label' to want to investigate further.

Comment: Worth noting that the markup does't seem to work for me, so used this instead: 

`<ion-list>  
      <ion-item>  
        <ion-label stacked>Username</ion-label>  
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="username" type="text" ngControl="username"></ion-input>  
      </ion-item>  ... <
/ion-list>`